# How does Solenoid works? How do I calculate its output power?

Tags: electromagnetism, coil, solenoid, solenoid-valve

[image: Solenoid of solenoid valve]

Here is a solenoid valve. It is a normally closed, which is mean, it is normally closed the valve. Vice versa, there is also normally open, which is mean, it is normally open the valve until it supplied with electric power to pull the rod. This type of solenoid available DC and AC current source.

What my concern here are how it work? How do I calculate its power requirement (Voltage, current), and its output power to force or to pull the rod so it close or open the valve as I explained above. What should be calculate here, is it B (magnetic field), or F (force)? And how to calculate it?

Comment: Read the device's data sheet.

Comment: Well the voltage is written on the label. The current is something you could measure.

Comment: [I disagree with] those who associated my post/question to that one. They absolutely are different. I am asking *How do I calculate its output power*. Very clear I explained in the body what I was asking. Absolutely, this is not product specific. It is general or theoritical. [Edited by a moderator to comply with the Code of Conduct.]

Comment: @user253751, you need to read before commenting. My whole question is about how to calculate the power of the rod by the solenoid. I also asked, what should I calculate, should be B (magnetic field), or F (force). Intuitively, thrust to the solenoid rod is a force, so it should be something like force, Newton.

Comment: @Andyaka, no datasheet available. Moreover, I am asking how to calculate.

Comment: [Try this for a start](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/102447/how-much-force-does-a-solenoid-really-have) or [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/322573/why-my-two-coils-dont-repel-each-other/322576#322576)